# Customizing bootstrap in custom.scss in dotnet core react template

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using the dotnet core React template in Visual studio 2017. This template is documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

It comes with a custom.scss file and reactstrap.  Is it possible to use bootstrap mixins to customize bootstrap using this custom.scss file out of the box or does this require extra configuration?

For example I added the following but this seems to do nothing:

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
    .btn-block-md {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to use bootstrap mixins to customize bootstrap using this custom.scss file out go the box or does this require extra configuration?

**The `Custom.scss` is not used and has been removed from the latest source**, See [commit#66fd4be4d7f1635368c4386f432daa7a22363d58](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/commit/66fd4be4d7f1635368c4386f432daa7a22363d58#diff-807b4b526378d54cb9271ce481c4dbe2). For more details, see [discussion here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/10247#discussion_r285297587)

Although the `custom.scss` is not used, you could easily custom the bootstrap with the built-in `react-scripts`. As [the official documents](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet) describes, you need update the `react-scripts` dependency to `@2.0.0`and higher.

Be aware the latest [`react-scripts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) requires dependencies on `eslint`, `babel-eslint` etc, don't try to manage these dependencies manually, just let the npm manages them:

1. Delete `package-lock.json` (not `package.json`) & `yarn.lock` file
2. Delete `node_modules` in your project folder.
3. Remove `babel-eslint`,`eslint`,`eslint-config-react-app`, and all `eslint-plugin-*` dependencies in the `package.json` file (Because they'll be managed by npm)
4. Update the `react-scripts` dependency in `package.josn` to `"react-scripts": "^2.0.0",`
5. Run `npm i` to install dependencies

And then install the `node-sass`:

```
npm install node-sass --save
```

Now you could custom the bootstrap as you like.

---

For example, let's create a `src/Custom.scss` file and change the `primary` to `darkgreen`:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": darkgreen,
);

// as suggested by @mutex, it's better to reference by `bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss`
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

To enable this configuration, remove the compiled `css` and import this new `scss` file in the `src/index.js`:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import "./custom.scss"
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

...
```

You'll find the `primary` color has been changed to `darkgreen`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks,+1 and I will definitely give this a try and mark as answer if it all works when I have time.  You've really gone above and beyond because I was mainly just confused by the presence of the custom.scss file... the discussion you link answered my main question.  Yeah I think it makes sense they've removed it!

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!   The only minor change I had was I used import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"  instead of  import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap" in my custom.scss -  was there a need for referencing the node_modules folder in yours?  I also needed the scss extension on the end of the import.

Comment: @mutex You're absolutely right. I wrote `../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap` just because I didn't remember the path :P , so just let the npm extension witin my VSCode help me .... Actually, it works pretty fine if I change it to `@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";` . There's no need to add a `../node_modules` prefix.